# Electron App Exit immediately after printing command

Tags: javascript, html, electron

i'm trying to create a desktop app that can do printing after i clicked some button.
so here is my code.

main.js

```
const {app,BrowserWindow} = require('electron');

function createWindow(){
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        resizable:false
    })
    win.maximize()
    win.removeMenu()
    win.loadFile("./index.html")

    win.webContents.on('did-create-window',(window,detail)=>{
        window.removeMenu()
        window.resizable = false
        window.webContents.print({silent:false})
    })
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow()
  
    app.on('activate', () => {
      if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow()
      }
    })
  })
  
  app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
      app.quit()
    }
  })
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    whatever
    <button onclick="newPrint()">BIGGIE</button>
</body>
<script>
    function newPrint(){
        var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200,height=100");
        myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'MsgWindow'. I am 200px wide and 100px tall!</p>"); 
    }
</script>
</html>
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "electron-print",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^19.0.2"
  }
}
```

[image]

So after i clicked the button, the electron app just suddenly close ! i just don't know why it happened.

and i tried re-creating this app on other computer (Mine was running Win 11 and i thought maybe that was the problem) and it worked just fine !

Could it be that Electron is not fully compatible with Win 11 yet ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems very much like [this Electron bug](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/34358), which is fixed in Electron 19.0.2 which you're apparently on.

Can you reinstall your node modules to confirm that you still see the issue in 19.0.2? This issue would have been present in Electron 19.0.1.

Comment: yeah, tried it and it work just fine now !